# Template Specialization for Template Template Parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I created a template class with template template parameters in .h file:

```
template<typename Index=Date, typename Value=double, template<typename> 
class Container=std::vector> class FastDataSeries
```

Then I try to specialize it in .cpp file so as to utilize the C++11 "extern template" feature in other file,

```
    template<> class FastDataSeries <Date, double, std::vector >;
    template<> class FastDataSeries <int, double, std::vector >;
```

Then I got the error message as below:

> ../src/timeseries/FastDataSeries.cpp:13:61: error: type/value mismatch
>   at argument 3 in template parameter list for ‘template class Container> class
>   MarketRisk::FastDataSeries’   template<> class FastDataSeries ;
>                                                                ^ ../src/timeseries/FastDataSeries.cpp:13:61: error:   expected a
>   template of type ‘template class Container’, got
>   ‘template class std::vector’
>   ../src/timeseries/FastDataSeries.cpp:14:60: error: type/value mismatch
>   at argument 3 in template parameter list for ‘template class Container> class
>   MarketRisk::FastDataSeries’   template<> class FastDataSeries ;
>                                                               ^ ../src/timeseries/FastDataSeries.cpp:14:60: error:   expected a
>   template of type ‘template class Container’, got
>   ‘template class std::vector’ make: ***
>   [src/timeseries/FastDataSeries.o] Error 1

What's the correct grammar to do this?

Comment: `std::vector` has more than one template argument. Either account for the specific missing arg(s) or load up a variadic arg solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
template<typename>
```

This does not match the templates of std::vector.You have to provide all template parameters.

```
template<class T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T> class Container
```

Comment: A standard library implementation is free to add as many additional template parameters as it likes, as long as they're defaulted. So, as @WhozCraig mentioned, a variadic solution is called for here (and even that isn't foolproof, as the stdlib may add non-type template parameters).

Comment: @ildjarn Actually, I'm fairly sure they can't add extra template parameters. See [LWG issue 94](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-closed.html#94).

Comment: @T.C. : Indeed, you're correct; it seems I was thinking of extra (defaulted) parameters for member functions of standard library types.